# Dúvida - Query SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

estou com dúvidas em como escrever uma query. Seguem as informações do problema:

- Tenho 3 tabelas, sendo a primeira uma tabela de cadastro de atletas (id, nome, idade, país...), uma segunda tabela com dados de desempenho dos atletas em jogos de verão (id do atleta, ano da competição, medalha (ouro, prata ou bronze) e uma terceira tabela com os mesmos dados da anterior mas para jogos de inverno.
- Um atleta pode ter competido em mais de um ano e tanto nos jogos de verão quanto inverno. Ex: Atleta A participou dos jogos de verão de 2012, 2013 e 2014 e de inverno de 2013 e 2015. Não obrigatoriamente ele ganhou medalha em todas as edições que participou.

Preciso montar uma query que me retorne todos os atletas que ganharam mais de duas medalhas de ouro, independente se foram em jogos de verão, inverno ou nos dois.

Seguem exemplos das estruturas das tabelas.

> ```
> Tabela A - Cadastro
> Id | Nome | Idade | País | Peso | Altura
>
> Tabela B - Jogos de verão
> Id_Atleta | Ano | Qntd Medalhas Ouro | Qntd Medalhas Prata | Qntd Medalhas Bronze
>
> Tabela C - Jogos de inverno
> Id_Atleta | Ano | Qntd Medalhas Ouro | Qntd Medalhas Prata | Qntd Medalhas Bronze
> ```

Preciso que a tabela resultante seja semelhante a essa:

> ```
> Id | Nome | Qntd Total Medalhas Ouro (mais do que 2 medalhas)
> ```

Tentei escrever query usando Join e Subqueries, mas não consegui chegar em alguma que me traga os resultados corretos. Alguém teria uma ideia de como posso escrever? Por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Olha como é bom modelar, se fosse eu tinha construído a tabela `B` e `C` em uma só colocando um `flag` para **V** - *Verão* e **I** - *Inverno*.

Do jeito que está complica o fácil que o mostrar o duas informações do atleta e sua quantidade de medalha de ouro (sendo os que tem mais de duas medalhas), basicamente no seu modelo é:

```
SELECT Tabela_A.id, Tabela_A.nome, sum(Tabela_D.quantidade_ouro) as ouro
  FROM Tabela_A 
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT * FROM Tabela_B
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM Tabela_C) Tabela_D 
ON Tabela_d.id_atleta = Tabela_A.id
GROUP BY Tabela_A.id, Tabela_A.nome
HAVING ouro > 2
```

[Exemplo Online - http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b98cd/1/0)